# Fill C++ Cinder textures with RGBA values

Tags: c++, textures, pixel, cinder

I use the Cinder Library and want to create a texture, filled with RGBA values which I saved in an array. There is no helpfull explanation on the internet.

Comment: Have a look at the surface basic sample: https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/samples/SurfaceBasic/src/SurfaceBasicApp.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used cinder before but a quick perusal of the documentation seems to suggest you can load a texture either form a file or from a Surface.

So looking at the [docs](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.6/classcinder_1_1_surface_t.html) it would seem you create a surface as follows:

```
cinder::Surface8u surf( 128, 128, SurfaceChannelOrder::RGBA );
```

You can then fill it using the [getData](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.6/classcinder_1_1_surface_t.html#a87dd5a31c22eab567c6d6be938518cd6) function as follows:

```
uint8_t* pCols = surf.getData();
for( int y = 0; y < 128; y++ )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < 128; x++ )
    {
        // Fill each pixel with red.
        const idx = (y * (128 * 4)) + (x * 4);
        pCols[idx + 0] = 0xff;
        pCols[idx + 1] = 0x00;
        pCols[idx + 2] = 0x00;
        pCols[idx + 3] = 0xff;
    }
}
```

You would then load the texture from the surface as follows:

```
cinder::gl::Texture texture( surf );
```